# Python Simplemonitor does not send out email on alert; possible configuration error

Tags: python, email, url, configuration, monitor

I'm setting up simplemonitor, found [here](https://github.com/jamesoff/simplemonitor), to have a check for the urls of my webservice.  If any check fails, then it should send out an email alert.

So far, I've confirmed that the monitor works properly.  However, when I shut down the service to check the email alert, it errors on sending an email:

```
2020-04-10 20:03:00  WARNING (simplemonitor) monitor failed but within tolerance: test-check
2020-04-10 20:03:10    ERROR (simplemonitor) monitor failed: test-check (Requests exception while opening URL: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.test.com', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /hello (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fef7c8762e8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)))
2020-04-10 20:03:10    ERROR (simplemonitor.alerter-email) couldn't send mail
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/envs/alertenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/simplemonitor/Alerters/mail.py", line 127, in send_alert
    server = smtplib.SMTP(self.mail_host, self.mail_port)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/envs/alertenv/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/envs/alertenv/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/envs/alertenv/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 307, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/envs/alertenv/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 712, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 703, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Here is the monitor.ini file to set up the rules:

```
[monitor]
monitors=/home/user/monitor/monitors.ini
interval=10

[reporting]
loggers=logfile
alerters=email

[logfile]
type=logfile
filename=monitor.log
only_failures=1

[email]
type=email
host=host.domain.com
from=simplemonitor@company.com
to=user@company.com
```

And the monitors.ini file that defines *what* I'm monitoring:

```
[test-check]
type=http
url=http://www.test.com:8080/hello
tolerance=1
```

I'm running it with `simplemonitor --config monitor.ini &>> monitor.log &`.

Given that I only started using this, I'm not sure if this is due to a error in the code, or one on my part due to a mistake in setup.

EDIT: I feel silly.  The bug was due to a typo in the monitor.ini file.  I'd misspelled the name of the smtp server in the host variable.  It now sent an email.  I apologize for any bother.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in an edit to the original question, this was due to a typo in the ini file for the smtp server name, in `host`.  I apologize for any bother this caused.